# Find and replace all NewLine or BreakLine characters with \n in a String - Platform independent

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a proper and robust way to find and replace all `newline` or `breakline` chars from a `String` independent of any OS platform with `\n`.

This is what I tried, but didn't really work well.

```
public static String replaceNewLineChar(String str) {
    try {
        if (!str.isEmpty()) {
            return str.replaceAll("\n\r", "\\n")
                    .replaceAll("\n", "\\n")
                    .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "\\n");
        }
        return str;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log this exception
        return str;
    }
}
```

Example:

Input String:

```
This is a String
and all newline chars 
should be replaced in this example.
```

Expected Output String:

```
This is a String\nand all newline chars\nshould be replaced in this example.
```

However, it returned the same input String back. Like it placed \n and interpreted it as Newline again.
Please note, if you wonder why would someone want `\n` in there, this is a special requirement by user to place the String in XML afterwords.

Comment: Why didn't it work well? You wrote expected output string, why not put the actual output?

Comment: Found my mistake, it should ne `\\\\n`, weird

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want literal `\n` then following should work:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "\\\\n")
```

Comment: :-)
Could you please explain a little, why \\n didn't work, but \\\\n. It works well with C# . So what's that Java does differently?

Comment: Actually in Java 2nd argument of `String#repalceAll` also required double escaping as the 1st argument since there can be use of `$1`, `$2` etc. So `\` is entered as `\\\\`

Comment: Hello I have done to replaced the newline character. Can you please post the expression where I get the original string.

Comment: @zeus: Didn't get your comment. And comment is not the right place to ask a new question, just post a new question and I'll attend it.

Comment: I mean to say I have executed a "String repl = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "\\\\n")" this and my string is changed. Now I want to get back my native string which I prepared earlier then what will be required,

Comment: `str` is your original string and `repl` is the new one.

Comment: String repl = str.replace("\r\n", "\\n");

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work well:

```
String s = "This is a String\nand all newline chars\nshould be replaced in this example.";
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[\\n\\r]+", "\\\\n"));
```

By the way, you don't need to catch exception.

Comment: Thanks, still confused why \\n didn't work. I am in a complete C# mode unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Oh sure, you could do it with one line of regex, but what fun is that?

```
public static String fixToNewline(String orig){
    char[] chars = orig.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
    for(char c : chars){
        switch(c){
            case '\r':
            case '\f':
                break;
            case '\n':
                sb.append("\\n");
                break;
            default:
                sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   String s = "This is \r\n a String with \n Different Newlines \f and other things.";

   System.out.println(s);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Now calling fixToNewline....");
   System.out.println(fixToNewline(s));

}
```

The result

```
This is 
 a String with 
 Different Newlines  and other things.

Now calling fixToNewline....
This is \n a String with \n Different Newlines  and other things.
```

Comment: Thanks, found my mistake, please have a look at my comment to the question.

Comment: Just use replace method: String repl = str.replace("\r\n", "\\n");