# Replace line break with escape character

Tags: java, excel, escaping

I have an app where I read data from an Excel and write it on a txt. I am reading cells from an excel, which may come with a line break. For example, I can read:

> Hello
>
> how are you?

Which is read as the following image

[image: Evaluate expression]

I have to save it in one line, with the corresponding escape characters. It must look this way.

[image]

But is being saved like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing?* - code, for one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909669/2574066)

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "\\\\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape your `\` before saving.

```
String escaped = string.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");
```

Comment: This does not work, as the result is "Hello n how are you?"

Answer (score 0):

You need escape character "\", so treat your text as:

```
"Hello \\n how are you?"
```