# RESTful service call

Tags: java, rest

I am using a chrome plugin and can successfully get my service to work:

[image]

I am now trying to get this same thing into my Java call. I'm having issues getting the Raw part into my Java service though. Any ideas?

```
  httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
  nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "Bearer " + token));
  nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));

  //I know this part is incorrect, but I don't know what to do with it
  nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("{\"pCode\": \"\", \"rType\": \"Sales Case\", \"subject\": \"test3\", \"description\": \"test4\", \"lookupInfo\": \"test5\", \"aaNum\": \"\"}", ""));

  try
  {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  HttpResponse response;
  try {
    response = client.execute(httpPost);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String builder = "";

    String line = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("line = " + line);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: @ZerO How do you think I got through all of the other code?  I'm stuck at this point and can't find how to do that last part.

Comment: @ZerO No... I don't.  I already know my code works.  Before this I do some authentication and get the expected response.  Now I'm making a call with the authenticated token that was returned from my earlier call.  Instead of nitpicking and giving me useless information try being helpful.  There isn't even a such thing as **.connect()** in the post.

Comment: how can i see that if you didn't post it? `I already know my code works.` so what you ask for???

Comment: What does happen? Are you getting an exception? No response data? Have you tried seeing what gets sent on the wire (tcpdump or similar) or added logging to your service to see if what you think is happening is actually happening?

Comment: Dude, you've got to improve this question.  What are you getting in your Java code?  What are the imports involved here?  Like what library does HttpPost come from.  The suggestion below that you save your sanity and get onto HttpClient is a good one.  Where you say "I know this isnt correct" is where you want to put that JSON into the request body not the request headers.

Comment: Holy crap this community is horrid.  I ask a legitimate question and instead of trying to be useful or ask for any useful clarifications I have people attacking my question.

Comment: @Baldy I'm not worried about what is working right now or isn't.  The first picture shows the setup that works.  The raw part is my JSON string that I don't know how to add to the call on top of the other paramaters.  I am using apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HttpClient

I have no idea what you are using to do your http calls, but for simplicity and sanity, use the httpclient from apache.

### Example

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token));
    post.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"));

    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
    StringBody pCode = new StringBody("SOME TYPE OF VALUE", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    StringBody rType = new StringBody("SOME TYPE OF VALUE", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    //
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addPart("pCode", pCode);
    builder.addPart("rType", rType);
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    try
    {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpResponse response;
    try {
       response = client.execute(httpPost);
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
       String builder = "";

       String line = in.readLine();
       System.out.println("line = " + line);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

This code has not been tested.

## UPDATE

JSON IS just a fancy string (in java's perspective) so just add the following:

```
builder.addPart("someName", new StringBody(json, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

## UPDATE 2

The above adds the JSON as a POST variable, not as the body.. [Look AT This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854115/in-java-using-httppost-apache-commons-httpclient-when-sending-json-post-sho)

Comment: Thanks.  I am using HttpClient from apache.  I'll have to test and see if it works tomorrow.

Comment: You don't need to use multipart here. The request he's making is an http post request with a json body. I don't know how this is exactly done with this client, but I'm sure it's not with multipart.

Comment: If he wants to stick with purely httpPost, he could get away with it. But as it is layed out before me, he's going to end up using a multipart with a body. So its there, for whenever he is ready. Plus, its the cleaner way of posting IMHO.

Comment: Also, the code provided by Ritesh Gune has DefaultHttpClient() - which is deprecated. Bad Code.

Comment: Perfect, your UPDATE 2 is what really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up headers and content:

These are headers:

```
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "Bearer " + token));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Cache-Control", "no-cache"));
```

And this is the content:

```
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("{\"pCode\": \"\", \"rType\": \"Sales Case\", \"subject\": \"test3\", \"description\": \"test4\", \"lookupInfo\": \"test5\", \"aaNum\": \"\"}", ""));
```

Here you set the content:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
```

You don't need to do multipart, just set the String content *without* encoding it, and set the headers with `httpPost.addHeader()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep header information and data at the appropriate place. Don't mix them up as you are doing now.

Understand the structure of `Http` requests:

1. A Start-line where 
   `start-line = Request-Line | Status-Line`

   eg. `GET /hello.htm HTTP/1.1`     (This is Request-Line sent by the client)
       `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`             (This is Status-Line sent by the server)
2. Zero or more header fields followed by CRLF (header information goes here)
   where `message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]`

   eg.

   ```
      User-Agent: curl/7.16.3 libcurl/7.16.3 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3  
      Host: www.example.com
      Accept-Language: en, mi    
      Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 12:28:53 GMT
      Server: Apache
      Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2009 19:15:56 GMT
      ETag: "34aa387-d-1568eb00"
      Accept-Ranges: bytes
      Content-Length: 51
      Vary: Accept-Encoding
      Content-Type: text/plain
   ```
3. An empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) indicating the end of the header fields
4. Optionally a message-body (content information goes here)

**You can try following:**

```
public void postData() {

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // pass the url as parameter and create HttpPost object.
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // Add header information for your request - no need to create 
    // BasicNameValuePair() and Arraylist.
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");    

    try {
    // put your content as follows:
    List<NameValuePair> form_data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
    form_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pCode", ""));
    form_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rType", "Sales Case"));
    form_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", "test3"));
    form_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", "test4"));
    form_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lookupInfo", "test5"));
    form_data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aaNum", ""));

    // pass the content as follows:
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form_data,
                        HTTP.UTF_8));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

    // TODO: Process your response as you would like.

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```